# How to get user current location

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

How to get user current location. I wants to track the speed of user and wants to draw the path when ever he move one to another place.

Comment: What you have tried for that

Comment: see this link https://www.raywenderlich.com/73984/make-app-like-runkeeper-part-1

Answer (score 0):

You can get user current location by CLLocationManager:

Add the following code win ViewDidLoad:

```
CLLocationManager  *objLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
objLocationManager.delegate = self;
objLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[objLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
[objLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Here is the delegate that returns the latitude and longitude:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
      CLLocation *currentLocation = locations; 
}
```

Comment: Actually it'll also return coordinates while we shaking iPhone. So we need the current coordinates only when we move not while we shaking the iPhone.

Comment: @AnilMatrid Shaking a phone also means that it is changing its location so it will definitely return the location even when you are shaking.

Comment: Yes you are right. But is there any way to get location only when we move, not when we shaking. Actually I wants to draw the path. So when I am shaking my iphone it'll draw the path without my movement. Thanks for your response.

Comment: You can set a range for drawing a path.If it is changing at some particular limit. You can draw a path.